# Device can't start error code 10

Tags: windows, security, windows-xp, usb

My (office) Desktop PC have some restrictions to USB devices. From the domain server there are some policies imposed.

1. If I insert USB Mass Storage device like a memory stick, my system is able to detect
2. If I insert a iPod, mobile or any other kind of devices, the driver installation may fail. the device manager reports error device can't start (error code 10).

I think it's the problem with registry permissions. is it possible to change this? Any idea? I'm running windows XP Professional 32 bit

Comment: You'll be better off working with your IT staff rather than coming up with a hack to circumvent organizational policy implemented from the domain.  This type of activity can quickly result in disciplinary action.  Unless I'm reading your question wrong....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll second @squillman - messing with your PC will only get you in trouble, and if it's secured properly, you most likely won't be able to tamper with it anyway. I'd rather talk to your Desktop Support/Sysadmin guy and see if he can allow you to use these devices.

Be nice to your IT people and they will be nice to you ;-).

If you DO have admin access you might be able to use gpedit.msc to edit the local policy and override whatever restrictions are in place. From what it sounds though, they might be using some kind of an Endpoint Protection product (3rd party). Use at your own risk :).

Comment: I'm nice to them. but I don't believe in some kind of rubbish policies. If I'm possible to plugin and use a memory stick, I believe I should not have any kind of restrictions with mass storage devices. Anyway I could not see any good information on USB devices information frmo gpedit.msc window :